# ExceptionMapper not working consistently in Jersey 2.x & javax

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0, javax.ws.rs

I am using `javax and jersey` for my api application (exposing api endpoints)
I am trying to catch exceptions coming from fasterXml (on put and post calls) by having a Provider which implements ExceptionMapper.

My Problem is that on POST or PUT, whenever I am sending wrong attributes names, sometime my mapper catch the exceptions and sometime it doesn't.
For example:

1. Running my application once -> everything is working as expected, catching exceptions.
2. Running my application again (restart) -> the mapper does not catch nothing

I am using Jersey 2.x, hosting in tomcat (not using spring or anything like that).

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>api-service-endpoints</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>
            com.api.providers,
            com.api.resources
        </param-value>

    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Provider Code:

```
@Provider
public class JsonMappingExceptionProvider
    implements ExceptionMapper<JsonMappingException> {

public JsonMappingExceptionProvider() {
    log.info("JsonMappingExceptionProvider created..");
}

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(JsonMappingExceptionProvider.class);

@Override
public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException exception) {
    log.error("Error while parsing input", exception);
    Response response = createBadRequestResponse();
    return response;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with the help of [Jersey Exception mappers not working when jackson deserialization fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397647/jersey-exception-mappers-not-working-when-jackson-deserialization-fails?rq=1)

Since jersey is trying to find the best match for the given exceptions within it's list of mappers, you have to map your mapper to the exact exception you are trying to catch, since the order of the mapper is arbitrary. Jackson has it's own mapper for general json exception, therefore you should try to make your mapper catch the exceptions you want.